# Not showing the id in the screen when hovering

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, mapbox, geojson

I am using leaflet and mapbox and I use the function to print the id nuber on the screen when hovering over the line in the map.

```
geojson = L.geoJson(lines, {
    style: style,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);

var info = L.control();

info.onAdd = function (map) {
    this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info'); // create a div with a class "info"
    this.update();
    return this._div;
};


info.update = function (props) {
    this._div.innerHTML = '<h4><b>Links<b></h4>' +  (props ?
        '<b>Link' + props.id + '</b><br />'  
        : 'Hover over a link');


};

info.addTo(map);
```

The way I draw the line is by the following geoJSON file

```
var lines = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
            [103.85, 1.28992],
            [103.89, 1.294],
            [103.83, 1.216]
        ],
        "properties": { "id": "1" }
    }, {
        "type": "LineString",
        "properties": { "id": "2" },
        "coordinates": [
            [103.5, 1.292],
            [103.9, 1.4],
            [103.3, 1.21]
        ]
    }, {
        "type": "LineString",
        "properties": { "id": "3" },
        "coordinates": [
            [103.6, 1.291],
            [103.6, 1.39],
            [103.3, 1.29]
        ]
    }]
};
```

but when i hover over the line it shows "undefined" instead of showing the id.Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is the declaration of your `onEachFeature`? Where is `update` called from? Your code is incomplete.

---

Besides, your GeoJSON is non-conformant to the [GeoJSON specifications](http://geojson.org/). A `FeatureCollection` **must** contain `Feature`s, and each `Feature` **must** have a `Geometry`.

So instead of:

```
{
  "type": "LineString",
  "properties": { "id": "3" },
  "coordinates": [[103.6,1.291],[103.6,1.39],[103.3,1.29]]
}
```

it should be something like:

```
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [[103.6,1.291],[103.6,1.39],[103.3,1.29]]
    },
    "properties": {
        "id": "3"
    },
}
```